# If vault were magically pelted by stones the size of cannonballs for eternity, how long would it be able to keep its contents safe?

Tags: security, safety

If an average personal safe is somehow hit with stones the size of cannonballs for eternity, how long could it keep its contents safe? I don't think the contents matter that much but assume it is a rubber duck.

Comment: How long between each hit? How fast? Assuming 10 seconds and cannonball speeds, then I'd say between 10-20 seconds lol. The average personal safe is not that tough.

Comment: Five seconds between each hit and the hit can be anywhere on the safe.

Comment: What counts is how fast are the stones travelling when they hit. If they are travelling at the speed of a snail then the personal safe will be safe for all eternity. If they are travelling at the speed of cannon balls shot from a cannon then the first stone will burst it open.

Comment: To look it from another angle: how big is this vault relative to the stone? Standard-issue hotel room personal safes won't probably withstand the first or second shot. Vault with the size of a basement and thickness of a brick wall is a different problem entirely.

Comment: @Nuclear03020704 - the OP does specify "personal safe", which does kind of leave "bank vault" out of the question.

Comment: @jdunlop You are right. I realized too late that such safes are not "average" for personal uses.

Answer (score 9):

## Less Than a Minute

[This is a video of people dropping a 100kg hammer onto a safe from 45m up](https://youtu.be/1QNZjlHwARc?t=553).

At 45m, a projectile will be travelling at about 30m/s.  The average [carronade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carronade) has a muzzle velocity of 250 m/s.  The average carronade round shot was 17cm in diameter.

A granite carronade round shot would mass ~7kg, but as projectile energy correlates to the square of the velocity, the stone round shot's energy (7kg * (250m/s)^2 = 437kJ) is greater than the hammer's energy (100kg * (30m/s)^2 = 90kJ).

It'd be surprising if the safe withstood the first impact. It certainly wouldn't survive the first twelve.

Comment: Agree - many people don't realise that most small safes consist of two quite thin layers of steel sandwiching a much thicker layer of insulating material (to protect the contents of the safe from a fire, at least for some time).  When I was being taught explosive demolitions in the military there were a few very old safes that were given to us as targets, with instructions to open them.  Most of us overestimated how much of the wall thickness was steel and obliterated the safe and contents rather than merely breaching them, while only using only a small quantity of PE.